# Microsoft Azure with AngularJS - Data not being displayed in chart

Tags: json, angularjs, azure

I am able to view data locally, however when I open the Windows Azure cloud service application, there is no longer Json data being passed into my chart (http://dashboardexample.cloudapp.net/Home/Product). I get a message in the Console saying "Controller names should start with an uppercase character and end with the suffix Controller. For example: UserController.
The best practice for module names is to use lowerCamelCase. Check the name of "dx"." Not sure what is causing this issue. Any thoughts?

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.productSettings = {
        dataSource: new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            load: function () {
                var def = $.Deferred();
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                });
                return def.promise();
            }
        }),
        series: {
            title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
            argumentType: String,
            argumentField: "Name",
            valueField: "Cost",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#008B8B'
        },
        commonAxisSettings: {
            visible: true,
            color: 'black',
            width: 2
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: 'Dollor Amount'
        }
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/dx.chartjs.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ChartDesign.js")

<div ng-app="customCharts">
    <div ng-controller="ChartController">
        <div dx-chart="productSettings"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're still calling `localhost` instead of `http://dashboardexample.cloudapp.net` here: `url: 'http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart'`.

Comment: Ok, one second, I will test it.

Comment: Hmm, still no data for some reason.  I am wondering if it has something to do with permissions in Windows Azure not being able to pass in my Json object...

Comment: @GauravMantri Or do you think it has something to do with me needing a callback with http://dashboardexample.cloudapp.net url?

Comment: One more thing ... you're only calling `http://dashboardexample.cloudapp.net`. Please change it to `http://dashboardexample.cloudapp.net/Home/PostChart` or just `/Home/PostChart`. I just put this URL in the browser and got following JSON back: `[{"Name":"Learn SQL Server 2014","Cost":34.95},....`. HTH.

Comment: Good thought. I am publishing to cloud now. I will test as soon as it's finished.

Comment: I used /Home/PostChart and that solved the problem.  successful graph now on the cloud service.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As GauravMantri mentioned, you need to reference the name and location of your controller function.  Ex: I had to reference /Home/PostChart in my dataSource url.  this solved the issue.

**AngularJS**
    var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

```
app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.productSettings = {
        dataSource: new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            load: function () {
                var def = $.Deferred();
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/Home/PostChart'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                });
                return def.promise();
            }
        }),
        series: {
            title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
            argumentType: String,
            argumentField: "Name",
            valueField: "Cost",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#008B8B'
        },
        commonAxisSettings: {
            visible: true,
            color: 'black',
            width: 2
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: 'Dollor Amount'
        }
    }
})
```